# Sql insert not working with WPF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I use EF. My layered construction is like this:

- Presentation Layer : WPF Desktop Project.
- Data Layer: Contains mdf and edmx.
- Business Layer: Service layer connecting to database.

[image]

When I do an insert:

Presentation Layer:

```
private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    dealer_detail.Telephone = textTelephone.Text;
    dealer_detail.Abstract = textAbstract.Text;
    dealer_detail.Address = textAddress.Text;
    dealer_detail.CreatedDate = dealerDatePicker.SelectedDate;
    dealer_detail.Fax = textFax.Text;
    dealer_detail.Name = textName.Text;

    dealer.Email = textEmail.Text;
    dealer.Password = textPass.Text;

    var result = conn.CreateNewDealer(dealer, dealer_detail);

    if (result > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Yeni Bayii Oluşturuldu! \n Kayıt No:"+result);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Bayi Oluştururken Hata Oluştu!");
    }
}
```

Business Layer:

```
public int CreateNewDealer(DEALER dealer, DEALER_DETAIL dealer_detail)
{
    try
    {
        _db.DEALER_DETAIL.Add(dealer_detail);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {                
        throw;
    }

    return dealer.Id;
}
```

In the beginning, the table is empty:

[image]

I added the data and then selected. There seems to be one row of data.

[image]

But there is no data in the table.

Comment: You  right clicked the table and selected edit, that screen won't refresh, close that and just do a query (select * from YourTable)

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/qj8PyQ.png

Comment: Ok, please show your connection string in app.config or in web.config

Comment: Also, the method SaveChanges returns the number of rows affected, please try this `int x=_db.SaveChanges();` and check the value of x, it should be x=1

Comment: Connection string in Presentation Layer:

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AracBayiiEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CarDealer.csdl|res://*/CarDealer.ssdl|res://*/CarDealer.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\AracBayii.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Show both: in Data and Presentation layer

Comment: In both the same ConnectionString

Answer (score 1):

IT looks like you need to create the deal in the database first, then using the dealer.ID from the dealer, create the dealer_detail.  then return the ID.

```
var newDealer = _db.DEALER.Add(dealer);
dealer_detail.DealerID = newDealer.ID;
_db.DEALER_DETAIL.Add(dealer_detail);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

then return `newDealer.Id;`

Comment: you may have to modify the detail lines to : newDealer.Dealer_Detail.add(dealerDetail);